# Determining which columns to index in MySQL in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, database, cakephp, join, indexing

I have a web app, which has quite a few queries being fired from every page. As more data was added to the DB, we noticed that the pages were taking longer and longer to load.

On examining PhpMyAdmin -> Status -> Joins, we noticed this (with the number in red):

Select_full_join    348.6 k  The number of joins that do not use indexes. If this value is not 0, you should carefully check the indexes of your tables.

1. How do I determine which joins are causing the problems? Are all the joins equally to be blamed?
2. How do I determine which columns should be indexed, for the performance to be proper?

We are using CakePHP + MySQL, and the queries are all auto-generated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The rule of thumb that I have always used, is that if I am using join, the fields that I am joining on need to be indexed.

For instance, if you have a query like the following:

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.salary
    FROM employee AS t1 
    INNER JOIN info AS t2 ON t1.name = t2.name;
```

Both t1.name and t2.name should be indexed.

Below are some good reads for this as well:

[Optimizing MySQL: Importance of JOIN Order](http://www.webdevstuff.com/119/optimizing-mysql-importance-of-join-order.html)

[How to optimize MySQL JOIN queries through indexing](http://www.cryptkcoding.com/2012/04/how-to-optimize-mysql-join-queries-through-indexing/)

And in general, this guy's site has some good info as well.

[MySQL Optimizer Team](http://mysqloptimizerteam.blogspot.com/)

Edit: This is always helpful.

And if you have access to your server settings, check out:

[MySQL Slow Server Logs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html)

Once you have a log of slow queries, you can use explain on them to see what needs indexing.

Comment: So if I have a HABTM/Join table scenario, or a simple CakePHP model association scenario (say Post belongsTo User, Post has user_id), then what fields would I index? Isn't this an 'implicit' kind of join? Sorry I'm a complete newb at this.

Comment: Performance wise, there is little difference between explicit/implicit joins. In regards to which fields to index in your HABTM/Join, I would make sure that any field that I was using on the join, in the case of your previous comment, the user_id field in your Posts table, or anything that you are using as a foreign key essentially.

Comment: +1, thanks. Just what I wanted. I have an app that's gotten really really slow :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know which queries are running inefficiently, you have a couple of choices.

You could try this:

Try issuing the command `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` from phpmyadmin while your web site is active.  It will show you, hopefully, a bunch of slow running queries.  The `FULL` processlist should give you the entire query. You could then use the `EXPLAIN` command to figure out what it's doing.

You should also try this:

Think through the work your application is doing on behalf of your users.  Think through which of your queries have to romp through lots of data to deliver value to the users. Think through which tables are growing as your application gets used more and more.

Then, find your queries that deliver that value, and that access your growing tables.  Again, use the `EXPLAIN` command to see how MySQL is processing them, and add indexes as needed.

I suspect it will be very obvious which indexes you should add.  Add the obvious ones, then let your system stabilize for a couple of workdays, then remeasure.

Notice that this is a normal part of bringing a new application into production.

Comment: SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST is an incredible tool! Many thanks :) +!